# baixar pdf que está fora da aplicação jsf java

Tags: jsf, primefaces

preciso colocar pra download alguns pdf que estão fora da minha aplicação, estão na pasta c:\tmp\

como poderia fazer utilizando o primefaces para disponibilizar estes arquivos pra download?

eu pensei em salvar na pasta
C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\app.war\WEB-INF

mas cada vez que eu fizer o deploy este arquivo é eliminado

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

Declare um atributo do tipo `DefaultStreamedContent` no seu bean:
Exemplo:

```
private DefaultStreamedContent download;
```

Faça os Get e sets:

```
public DefaultStreamedContent getDownload() {
        return download;
    }

public void setDownload(DefaultStreamedContent download) {
        this.download = download;
}
```

Em seguida :

```
    //Método que faz o download do anexo
    public void prepDownload() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("c:/tmp/arquivo.pdf");

        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
    }
```

Depois no seu botão;

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s"
    title="Download Anexo"
    actionListener="#{bean.prepDownload()}"
    ajax="false">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.download}" />
</p:commandButton>
```